# javascript jsgantt to PDF

Tags: javascript

i am using jsGantt javascript library for showing gantt charts in html . now i want to save that generated ganttchart in PDF form how i will use that ??

the problem is with CSS , and JavaScript....

thank you ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a server-side script to do the HTML to PDF conversion, and then link to that script from your HTML report using a popup window.

If you're using PHP then [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.seven49.net/)  will do the trick, or [ABCPdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/addimageurl.htm) for a Microsoft platform.